# Can we create custom blur in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, blur

Can we create custom Blur in react native like @react-native-community/blur packages provides. That package works for ios but in android it creating lot of issues. It takes complete screen size. component does not follow contraints. I want exact component like first header in which producer is mentioned.

[Blur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKwUC.jpg)

Comment: You could have easily Googled this question

Answer (score 0):

I Just figured it we can resolve that issue in android by using inner and outer wrapper with blurview. [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YME2t.png)

that is a sample code working for me

```
Platform.OS == 'ios' ?
        (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <BlurView
                    style={styles.box_Wrappeer}
                    blurType="light"
                    blurAmount={10}
                >
                    <View style={styles.row_1}>
                        <View style={styles.row_1.first_part}>
                            <Image style={styles.row_1.image} source={icon} ></Image>
                            <Text style={styles.row_1.text}>{title}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row_1.second_part}>
                            <Image style={styles.row_1.image2} source={require('../../assets/cross_icon.png')}></Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.row_2}>
                        <Text style={styles.row_2.text}>
                            {user}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </BlurView>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ) :
        (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.box_wrapper_android}>
                <BlurView
                    style={styles.box_inner_wrapper_android}
                    blurType="light"
                    blurAmount={10}
                >
                    <View style={styles.box_Wrappeer}>
                        <View style={styles.row_1}>
                            <View style={styles.row_1.first_part}>
                                <Image style={styles.row_1.image} source={icon} ></Image>
                                <Text style={styles.row_1.text}>{title}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row_1.second_part}>
                                <Image style={styles.row_1.image2} source={require('../../assets/cross_icon.png')}></Image>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.row_2}>
                            <Text style={styles.row_2.text}>
                                {user}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </BlurView>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
```